# Coffee machine in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented

I've been struggling with python OOP. I've gone through the basics but I'm struggling with implementing them. So I've decided to create something small everyday while in quarantine to get more comfortable with OOP.

My code simulates a simple coffee machine that makes 4 types of coffee.

This is the first one. What do you think of it? How can I improve it?

```
import os
class Coffee:
    """ A generic coffee machine """

    def __init__(self, coffee, cups, water, milk, sugar):
        self.coffee = coffee
        self.cups = cups
        self.water = water
        self.milk = milk
        self.sugar = sugar

    def coffee_maker(self):
        preferred_coffee = type_of_coffee()
        sugar_intake = some_sugar()
        if sugar_intake in ("Y", "y"):
                self.sugar -= 5

        if preferred_coffee == 1:
            print("Espresso coming up!\n")
            print("1 Espresso delivered!")

        elif preferred_coffee == 2:
            print("Filtered Coffee coming up!\n")
            print("1 Filtered Coffee delivered!")

        elif preferred_coffee == 3:
            print("Latte coming up!\n")
            print("1 Latte delivered!")
            self.milk -= 30

        elif preferred_coffee == 4:
            print("Cappuccino coming up!\n")
            print("1 Cappuccino delivered!")
            self.milk -= 30

        self.coffee -= 140
        self.cups -= 1
        self.water -= 120

    def coffee_maker_report(self):  # returns the amount of: coffee, sugar, water, milk, cups left
        return {"Coffee": self.coffee, "Water": self.water, "Milk": self.milk, "Sugar": self.sugar, "Cups": self.cups}


def type_of_coffee():  # this function makes sure the user chooses a their coffee of choice by getting ONLY a valid
    # input
    print("Hi there, what would you like to drink")
    coffee_list = ["1 - Espresso", "2 - Filter", "3 - Cappuccino", "4 - Latte"]

    valid = False
    while not valid:
        try:
            choice = int(input("Enter Choice: "))
            if choice in (1, 2, 3, 4):
                valid = True
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid option.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid option")

    return choice


def some_sugar():

    valid = False

    while not valid:
        try:
            choice = input("Some sugar? ")
            if choice in ("Y", "y", "N", "n"):
                valid = True
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid option")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid option")

    return choice


def main():
    os.system("cls")
    new_coffee = Coffee(3500, 25, 3000, 750, 125)  # mg, no., ml, ml, mg
    print(new_coffee.coffee_maker_report())
    new_coffee.coffee_maker()
    print(new_coffee.coffee_maker_report())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Check the post https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237467/decorator-visitor-pattern-in-python for an explanation of a visitor pattern, specially for the coffee_maker function

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful, I learned something new.